# Check that django already execute query and get data from database

Tags: django, model

How can I check that django has already executed query and retrieved data from database.

For example, I have product and category models,

```
if product.category:
```

In this case, If django no data of category, it executes the query and retrieves category data from db.

How i can check If it already has the data?

Comment: user 'if hasattr(product, 'category')' and if it exists, you can do if product.category. hope this is useful..

Answer (score 0):

You can check raw field instead of a foreign key to another model like this:

> if product.category_id:

If there are queryset you can retrieve `category` together with `products` qs in one request, using sql joins:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Or prefetch this field without joins:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Answer (score 0):

You should [use a cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/) if you want to avoid fetching things unnecessarily:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
from .models import Product

def someview(request, pk=None):
    product = cache.get_or_set(pk, Product.objects.get(pk=pk), 100)
    # do your normal stuff with product
```

The `get_or_set` method works like this:

```
get_or_set(key, new_value_to_set, expiry_in_seconds)
```

It tries to fetch an object from the cache with the key, if it doesn't exist, it will set it to the second argument, and let it expire for the value in the third argument.

Comment: Won't `Product.objects.get(pk=pk)` always be called since it will be evaluated for `get_or_set`?